# Surjective image space with function entries

Tags: linear-algebra

The kernel space U in a vector space defined by morphism $T: V \to W$ is defined by set $\{v \in V \, \vert \, T v = 0 \}$. such that $U \subset V$. The image set is given as $\{w \in V \, \vert \, y = T w \}$. These definitions are broad enough and only require vector $v$ and $w$ belonging to vector space $V$.

I got an example such that matrix $T = \begin{bmatrix} x & -y \end{bmatrix}$, for entries $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. For certain quantity $y = z$, we have multiple vectors $v$ e.g. $\frac{1}{x^{n} + y^{n}} \begin{bmatrix} x^{n-1} \\ -y^{n-1} \end{bmatrix} z$. Why does this happen? Can the same happen for kernel space? I mean, can a linear transformation be surjective?

Thanks!

Comment: "I mean, can a linear transformation be surjective?" Let us assume that $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$. Then your matrix $T$ IS already surjective! It maps from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$. So, it maps from a larger space to a smaller space. Take the one-dimensional subspace $\{(t,0) : t\in\mathbb R\}$. This subspace is already mapped to all of $\mathbb R$. So, where should the rest go? Think about it.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds very obvious as you say it

Comment: I still do not understand what do you mean with 'where should the rest go?'. Do you mean, the complement $(0, y)$?

Comment: Your description of the image is wrong. The image is $\{w\in W\mid w=Tv\text{ for some }v\in V\}$ or $\{Tv\in W\mid v\in V\}$. What you write is not even a well-formed formula; it is meaningless. The variable $y$ is not bound, and you define it as a subset of $V$.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, @ArturoMagidin